# Issue with printing arrays in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm seeing something weird when I try to include the ember.js library (ember-1.0.0-rc.7.js).

The javacode I have just prints out a javascript array:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var songs = [ 'a','b','c'];

console.debug(songs.toString());
for(key in songs)
{
    console.debug(songs[key]);
}

</script>
```

When I don't include the library, it'll print out a , b, c in the console.  However, when i do include it, it start printing out a, b, c, but as well as all the functions to...

Example:

```
function (idx) {
    return this.objectAt(idx);
  }
function superWrapper() {
    var ret, sup = this._super;
    this._super = superFunc || K;
    ret = func.apply(this, arguments);
    this._super = sup;
    return ret;
  }
function (key) {
    return this.mapProperty(key);
  }
```

Any reason why this occurs with the ember.js library, and how do I resolve this issue?

Any advice appreciated,
Thanks,
D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Ember extends built-in prototypes such as `Array.prototype` to provide extra methods or shim ES5 methods for non-supporting browsers. You are seeing these methods because [`for...in` iterates over the *enumerable properties of an object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). These include *all* properties, even those inherited through the prototype chain.

Instead, you should use a regular `for` loop to iterate over an array:

```
for(var i=0; i<songs.length; i++) {
    console.debug(songs[i]);
}
```

This will only ever go over actual array elements, i.e. properties with a numerical key. There are nicer ways though, for example using ES5 `Array.forEach` (shimmed by Ember in older browsers):

```
songs.forEach(function(song, i) {
    console.debug(song);
});
```

Optionally, you can disable Ember's prototype extension by configuring [`Ember.EXTEND_PROPERTIES`](http://emberjs.com/api/#property_EXTEND_PROTOTYPES) if you're not planning to use them or if they might conflict with other libraries/scripts. There's [a whole page](http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/) dedicated to this issue in the Ember documentation.

Answer (score 2):

embjer.js must be adding functions to the native Array.prototype. You can check if each key is actually a property on the array itself, and not an inherited property, using [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
for(key in songs) {
    if(songs.hasOwnProperty(key)){ 
        console.debug(songs[key]);
    }
}
```

But, it is usually recommended to always use ordinary for loops with arrays, since they have numerical keys:

```
for(var i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
    console.debug(songs[i]);
}
```

You can also use the [forEach function](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_forEach) that, ironically, Ember added to the Array prototype if it didn't already exist (in older browsers).

```
songs.forEach(function(song){
    console.debug(song);
});
```

### Demo

Comment: Yeah thanks just read this http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/